# Change main viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using multiple viewcontrollers but need to change which who loads first. I have found some old tips but those are regarding .nib files and I belive those might not be up to date. Preferably I'd like to find some option in the menu's, as I frankly think this should be very simple.

Any ideas to a simple way of changing with viewController is loaded first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the storyboard file
- Display the document outline
- Select the view controller that you want to be first
- Under the "Attributes inspector", select "Is Initial View Controller"

Comment: I appreciate all the answers! 
This one in particular though, as I was looking for a menu option to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically load a view controller first through your `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewContoller = <firstViewControllerIWantToLaunch>;
    return YES;
}
```

This ensures that the view controller you want to load first is the root view controller, and will be the first view controller presented.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard, select the view controller you'd like, and search for the "Is initial view controller" checkbox. I can't tell you where exactly it is, since I don't have Xcode open.

If you're using xibs, you need to change it in the AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. (Refer to Bryan's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between the two view controllers programmatically, Try  doing Some thing Like this, 
     In your AppDelegate.m file in 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions.. Method

just place this condition..

If(loadFirstView){

```
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController       *)self.window.rootViewController;
    FirstViewController *menu = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FIrstVC"];


    navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menu, nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}else{
     UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController       *)self.window.rootViewController;
    SecondViewController *menu = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];


    navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menu, nil];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Don't Forget to assign StoryboardIDentifiers "FirstVC" and "SecondVC" in your storyboard file…This should do it, It works Well for me

Answer (score 0):

As already answered here, you need to select your project's main storyboard file, select the main view controller, go to attributes inspector and, check the checkbox title "Is Initial View Controller" to make main view controller loading as first view controller upon app launch.

[image: This should help]